# NSURLSessionUploadTask originalRequest httpBody is Null

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am using `NSURLSessionUploadTask` to upload an image.

**The upload works. The image is successfully posted to my server.**

This is the method that is called creates a new `NSURLSessionUploadTask`. The `NSData` is the image in `NSData` format, and the `withPostRequest:` is a `NSMutableRequest` with all the junk that goes in that.

```
- (void) uploadImage:(NSData*)data withPostRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*)postRequest {

    NSURLSessionUploadTask * uploadTask = [_session uploadTaskWithRequest:postRequest fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {

            //MAIN THREAD ACCESS UPDATE TO THE GUI OR DISPLAY ERRORS
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

               //UPDATE THE GUI ON COMPLETION
            });

        }];

        // START THE TASK
        [uploadTask resume];
}
```

This delegate method gets called with the upload to show the progress. This method IS called upon ever successful byte sent.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {

NSData * taskData = [task.originalRequest HTTPBody];
            NSLog(@"Task Data: %@", taskData);

}
```

However, if I have multiple uploads, I need to be able to check which upload has the correct progress. I feel like you can do this by comparing the task.originalRequest `NSData`, with the known `NSData` of the passed Image.

However, when the above method is called, `[task.originalRequest HTTPBody]` is ***NULL***

Does anyone know why that would be null?

Comment: Why don't you check  [task.originalRequest URL] ?

Comment: If I have multiple uploads going at the same time, wouldn't the URL's be the same? Besides, the only unique thing about each is the NSData. The method *should* pass the NSData into the method but it doesn't.

Comment: Ok so all uploads are to the same server without any change in URL. Probably should mention that in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the `NSSessionUploadTask` and have an identifier assocciated with it.

```
@interface NSSessionUploadTaskId : NSObject {
   NSUInteger taskIdentifier;
}
```

`NSURLSessionTask` also has [`taskIdentifier` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontask/1411231-taskidentifier?language=objc) but I'm not sure how to use that.

> `@property(readonly) NSUInteger taskIdentifier;`
>
> An identifier uniquely identifies the task within a given session.